# how to implement ab+bc+ca using nor gates

Tags: digital-logic

How do I implement the function ab+bc+ca using nor gates only ?  I am having trouble figuring out all the steps.

Comment: Firstly check how AND and OR gates can be expressed in terms of NOR gates. Then put into your function f(a,b,c). The rest of the work is just making connections. Also, check this out -> https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because for homework-style questions, you need to show where exactly you're stuck. You say you didn't figure out *all* the steps - great! So show us what you've got so far, and you might get help at learning how to do the next steps and eventually solve things by yourself.

Comment: As @emreiris says, it's a straightforward application of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Here's a hint: Think about where the zeros are in the K-map instead of the ones.

Comment: I would start by listing a truth table so you know what output you want then look up De Morgan.  There is a simple relationship between AND gates and NOR gates.

Answer (score -1):

[image: CHECK THIS ANSWER]

Check this answer, Implemented using NOR gate...